# How to disable Android Studio code style warning "... can be simplified to ..."

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using `productFlavors` and `buildConfigField` to enable/disable features in my Android app:

```groovy
productFlavors {
    vanilla {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "FEATURE_SAR", "false"
    }
    edge {
        applicationIdSuffix ".edge"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "FEATURE_SAR", "true"
    }
}
```

Haven't found a way to disable Android Studio code style warning saying "'!BuildConfig.FEATURE_SAR' can be simplified to 'false'".

As you can see in my code, I've tried many ways but none of them works. And I cannot find the setting where I can disable this in Android Studio.

```java
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("SimplifiableIfStatement") // no effect
@SuppressLint("SimplifiableIfStatement")     // no effect
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Set<Integer> suppressPositions = new HashSet<>();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement <-- no effect
    if (!BuildConfig.FEATURE_SAR) {
        suppressPositions.add(IDX_SAR);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = ViewUtils.createSimpleAdapter(
        getContext(), MENU_RESOURCES, suppressPositions);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Of course there are ways to get around this by using resources, but for some reasons I cannot use resources in all cases. So the question is only how to disable these warnings, not how to better handle config management in Android/Gradle.

Comment: In general once you put the cursor into the warning press ALT + ENTER. Then enlarge the context-menu of your warning. There should be a entry "Disable Inspection" displayed with a red X

Comment: Thanks, it works. Copy and paste your comment as an answer and I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general once you put the cursor into the warning press ALT + ENTER. Then enlarge the context-menu of your warning. There should be a entry "Disable Inspection" displayed with a red X as shown here:

[image: Example]

Comment: With your help it turned out that I used the wrong inspection in code. Instead of `SimplifiableIfStatement` it was `PointlessBooleanExpression`. This can be applied to statement with `//noinspection` and to method or class with annotation `@SuppressWarning`.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case some more people stumble upon this rather old question.

You can also insert a statement instead of the final value, this way the IDE should not be able to determine if there is a pointless boolean expression or not:

```
buildConfigField("boolean", "FEATURE_STAR", "Boolean.parseBoolean(\"true\")")
```

The result in your `BuildConfig` will look like this:

```
public static final boolean FEATURE_STAR = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
```

Btw: This is the same mechanism by which `BuildConfig.DEBUG` will be generated.

Comment: An interesting way to solve this issue. Better than polluting the code with lint hints.